# Some of the images are not found(404) when all have correct full path and are in same folder

Tags: php, html, image, apache, codeigniter

I encountered this problem :

Some of the images I try to use in my website, did not show.
I use correct full domain path to the image files.

You can see the issue at this link :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPiZk.jpg

You can see on the first image that some of the images are loaded (the logo and the glyphicons from Bootstrap), while one is not loading (with response 404).

On the second image you can see that all the images are actually in the same folder, which is in the root of the domain.
I also checked that all files and the folder have same permissions.

The site is written using Codeigniter, and the links are generated dynamicly using the following code:

```
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/img/logo.png">

   <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/img/<?php echo $database_item ?>">
```

Where the image file name comes from the database.

You can also check my website at http://laskov.home.megalan.bg/index.php
and you can see that for all images the 'src' attribute produces exactly the same value for all images, except the image file name.
I use the same method for loading the CSS and JavaScript files which is working fine.

NOTE: If you check the site you can see other images are not loading and some of them are not really in the folder , but 'house.jpg' is still there and not loading.

Also when I use other images they are still not loading , I think only 'logo.png' and the Bootstrap glyphicons are actually loaded in the page.

The issue is there both on secure or unsecured connection.

I use PHP5 on Apache 2.22 (WAMP installation).

So does anyone have seen this before , and have some usefull tips for what might be going on?

Comment: Nope. Images are NOT there. Check your paths.

Comment: There is one path in this case, what should I check about it ? As seen in the screenshot there are more than 4 pictures there , but they cannot be seen from outside.

Answer (score 1):

You just mixed up something. E.g. the house.jpg should be here:

https://laskov.home.megalan.bg/img/

but everything i can see there is

```
[DIR]   Parent Directory         -   
[IMG]   glyphicons-halflings..> 17-May-2013 10:21   8.6K     
[IMG]   glyphicons-halflings..> 17-May-2013 10:21    12K     
[IMG]   logo.png    24-Jul-2013 20:30   722K     
[IMG]   winter_mountains-200..> 24-Jul-2013 20:11   1.2M
```

so - no it's definitly not there

Comment: Well marty , that is exactly the problem, as you can see in the screenshot , there are more pictures in the folder and they are definitly there, thats why Im confused about this and seek answer here in this forum :)